# Post data & show source code

Tags: php

I have question, is it possible to first post data to a site and then get the source code of the site I was posting the data to?

I tried with this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://test.com/test.php?test=test');
```

But the ?test=test is $_GET....

So yeah, I hope someone can help me! :) 
 Thanks in advance (Sorry for bad english!).

Comment: try a curl post http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: you can get html generated by request not sourcecode for that use curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3rd parameter of this function: *context*

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($postdata)."\r\n",
        'content' => $postdata
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

// edit -little bug should be:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".strlen($postdata)."\r\n",
        'content' => $postdata
  )
);
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that was b'cause I did "echo $result;" but I now I get this error:  Notice: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Look again on example, there is different header value.

Comment: Hm... What do you mean, and how can I change it?

Comment: I don't know what you exacly calling, maybe your headers isn't correctly.

Comment: You should add "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n". in header.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the source, but you can get the page/output as it is provided by the server. As you mention `file_get_contents()`, you can use it to send a POST-request, but it would look something like this.

```
// Create map with request parameters
$params = array ('surname' => 'Filip', 'lastname' => 'Czaja');

// Build Http query using params
$query = http_build_query ($params);

// Create Http context details
$contextData = array ( 
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                'content'=> $query );

// Create context resource for our request
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

// Read page rendered as result of your POST request
$result =  file_get_contents (
                  'http://www.sample-post-page.com',  // page url
                  false,
                  $context);

// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it
```

Example from: http://fczaja.blogspot.se/2011/07/php-how-to-send-post-request-with.html